# R how to create character vector of paths

Tags: r, path

I am following this tool set called IUTA that needs to create a vector of the character of paths.

The example in the program shows that I have to do the following:

```
## set the paths for the BAM file and GTF file 
## notice that the gtf file contains correct gene_id information 
bam.list.1<-system.file("bamdata",paste("sample_",1:3,".bam",sep=""), 
package="IUTA") 
bam.list.2<-system.file("bamdata",paste("sample_",4:6,".bam",sep=""), 
package="IUTA") 
transcript.info<-system.file("gtf","mm10_kg_sample_IUTA.gtf", 
package="IUTA")
```

Ok I tried that, but its not creating moving the path for all of my bam files nor my gtf file.

I get the following error, when I try to run the program as it can not find nor open my bam files.

```
IUTA(bam.list.1, bam.list.2, transcript.info, 
+      rep.info.1 = rep(1, length(bam.list.1)), 
+      rep.info.2 = rep(1, length(bam.list.2)), 
+      output.dir = paste(getwd(), "/IUTA", sep = ""), 
+      output.na = TRUE, 
+      genes.interested = "all")

All 8 cores on the machine will be used. 
Preparing indices of bam files ...... 
open: No such file or directory
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : failed to open SAM/BAM file 
file: ''
```

I was wondering what exactly, I am doing wrong. Also I am working from an external hard drive and I am in that particular directory as well.

Many thanks.

http://www.niehs.nih.gov/research/resources/assets/docs/iuta_pdf_manual_508.pdf

Comment: can't say I'm familiar with `IUTA` so I'll have to take a shot in the dark... have you tried specifying an absolute path for your files instead of the relative path?

Comment: Does the `IUTA` directory exist in your working directory? It may not create a new one for you. Try the examples in the manual exactly as they appear.

Comment: I was just able to figure this out. I had to move my directory into User/Username/library/R/library/IUTA/ folder.

Also R does not seem to like working with my external hard drive. Does anyone know why? Also why did I have to my folder into the IUTA's installed folder to get it work. Strange. Also this tool is not on CRAN. :\